# Isn't the -Wnonnull-compare warning misleading?

Tags: c, gcc

I have an API in which some functions are declared with the **nonnull** GCC function attribute, for example:

```
// declaration in .h
__attribute__((nonnull))
int foo(const char *bar);
[...]
// definition in .c
int foo(const char *bar) {
    if (bar == NULL)
        return -1;

    // do something with bar
    ...
}
```

but the NULL check is triggering the **-Wnonnull-compare** GCC warning.
The problem is that the documentation of the **nonnull** attribute says that it:

> causes the compiler to check that, in calls [...], arguments [...] are non-null.

The problem is that it doesn't say anything about runtime. So if I remove this check to please GCC, I may hide, or detect later than necessary, a bug in a calling program.

So should this warning be silenced in this kind of situation? Or is there some kind of error in the documentation making the code without the check, in fact, correct?

FTR, my compiler version is 11.4.0.

Comment: The language of the gcc documentation is not a crisp as the C standard, but I believe the intention of the attribute is to assert that the argument will never be NULL, allowing the compiler to assume that it's never NULL. Effectively it makes passing in NULL undefined behavior. So comparing an argument marked nonnull to NULL is nonsensical; such code can never be correct.

Comment: The [11.4.0 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.4.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) does say “causes the compiler to check that… arguments… are non-null.” This was changed in [later documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) to say “informs the compiler that… arguments… are non-null.” Maybe this was a documentation error. It is not *per se* turning on a check of the arguments; it is telling the compiler it may assume the arguments are non-null. So it is not the attribute you want.

Comment: Ok, but let's imagine that some one does something like:

```
ptr = strdup("some string");
// strdup fails and ptr is null, but user fails to check
foo(ptr);
```

?

(gosh, entering enter to post is a pain and so is not having formatting...)

Comment: On formatting, don't put a space after the opening triple backtick in a comment; I forget whether a space before the trailing triple backtick matters.  Test: ```no space before; space after ```

Comment: If the user does: `char *ptr = strdup("something"); foo(ptr);` and the `strdup()` fails, then the user has broken the contract with the function `foo()`, and all hell can (and probably will) break loose.  The attribute says the function will never be called with a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the -Wnonnull-compare warning misleading?

No. There was an error in [the GCC 11.4 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.4.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html). It gave an example for the `nonnull` attribute in which it said:

> For instance, the declaration… causes the compiler to check that, in calls to `my_memcpy`, arguments *dest* and *src* are non-null.

However, the non-example descriptive text for the attribute said something different (emphasis added):

> It indicates that the referenced arguments **must be** non-null pointers.

This was corrected in [the GCC 12.3 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), where the text about the example was changed to:

> For instance, the declaration… informs the compiler that, in calls to `my_memcpy`, arguments *dest* and *src* are non-null.

while the non-example descriptive text remained the same.

Thus, the `nonnull` attribute is an assertion to the compiler that it may assume the pointers are not null, and so the warning that you are comparing a non-null pointer to null is correct.

In conclusion, the `nonnull` attribute does not provide the feature that you want of reporting when a null pointer is passed for an argument that should not be null.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So concretely, IIUC the best option ATM is to:
* document clearly in the API that the argument passed must be NULL
* keep the non NULL check, to enforce it at runtime

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `__attribute__((nonnull))` seems to be completely equivalent to declaring the function as:
`int foo (const char bar[static 1])`.

In either case you wrote a contract with the compiler saying "I promise that this parameter will never be a null pointer, please generate code accordingly". As a bonus, some compilers may also give a diagnostic message if they can deduct on the caller side that a null pointer is passed.

The reason why you get a diagnostic message inside the function when checking vs NULL is because you already told the compiler that the parameter is never a null pointer and so the check is pointless.

Now if you don't have that check and the compiler cannot detect on the caller-side that a passed pointer is a null pointer (maybe because it happens in run-time) then indeed bad things may happen. In that situation, this attribute isn't the solution to the problem.

So what to do? You've already suggested the correct solution yourself, between the lines:

> So if I remove this check to please GCC, I may hide, or detect later than necessary, a bug in a calling program.

Bugs in the calling program should, unsurprisingly, be detected by the calling program. So *that* is where the null pointer check should be located. Ideally as close as possible to the situation where the pointer for one reason or another can become a null pointer.

Example of correct usage:

```
// caller application
int* data = malloc(n);
if(data == NULL) //  <--- correct placement of the null pointer check
{ /* error handling */
```

Example of incorrect usage:

```
// caller application
int* data = malloc(n);
...

// 5k LoC later...
some_unrelated_function(data);

void some_unrelated_function (int* data)
{
  if(data == NULL) // <--- WRONG PLACE
}
```

Notably:

- Bugs should be detected as early on as possible. User input should be sanitized at the point where user input is taken, by the code taking the user input.
- Unrelated library functions do not have the responsibility to detect bugs in the caller application nor sanitize user input. They should only do their designated task.
- Spamming `ptr == NULL` checks over every unrelated library function creates a significant execution time overhead of 100% useless branches. Particularly so if the library is performance critical, such as data copying functions etc that may be called repeatedly from a loop. Such superfluous error checking is a common non-veteran mistake in C.